# Смысловая разница в предложении

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика

> На встрече представителей двух государств принятые обязательства были успешно выполнены. **(Смысл данного предложения может быть понят так, что обязательства были выполнены на самой встрече.** Для устранения неточности необходимо исправить предложение следующим образом: **Обязательства, принятые на встрече представителей двух государств, были успешно выполнены.**)

Вопрос: Что изменилось после изменения порядка слов? В обоих предложениях обязательства были выполнены.  В первом - на встрече представителей. А во втором? Никак не могу понять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Важно то, **кем и когда** были выполнены обязательства.

В первом предложении они каким-то образом оказались выполнены представителями стран прямо на встрече - неужели это были обязательства поставить какие-то подписи?

Во втором предложении всё правдоподобно: на встрече обязательства были приняты представителями стран, выполнены они были позже и другими людьми - теми, кому поручили их выполнение.

Comment: А почему каким-то образом? Ваш второй  вариант кажется более логичным.

Comment: Потому что возникает вопрос о смысле такого предложения: _каким образом_ на встрече были выполнены упомянутые обязательства? Договориться на встрече можно, _взять_ обязательства можно, а _выполнить_ их - это обычно длительная работа.

Comment: Наверное вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

В первом предложении связь такая: обязательства (какие?) принятые были выполнены (где?) на встрече.

Во втором предложении обязательства (какие?), принятые на встрече, (причастный оборот) были выполнены (где и кем не уточняется)

Comment: В том-то и дело, что смысл заключается в том, что обязательства были выполнены не на самой встрече. А в первом варианте из-за порядка слов так и получается. Поэтому предложение переправлено. Изменился смысл. Просто не могу понять: на чем именно делается акцент во втором предложении. Вариант Александра мне нравится.Посмотрим, может, будут другие ответы.

Comment: Наталья Если Вы спрашиваете на чем делается смысловой акцент, то по-моему, в обоих предложениях - на "выполнены".  Кем и когда выполнены - не акцентируется, но разница именно в этой части. И эту разницу объяснил @Alex_ander

Answer (score 0):

Надо переставить обстоятельство "на встрече", **тогда оно будет относиться к причастию, а не к глаголу:**

а) Причастный оборот  в начале  предложения: Принятые  **на встрече** представителей двух государств обязательства были успешно выполнены.

б) Причастный оборот  середине предложения: Обязательства, принятые  **на встрече** представителей двух государств, были успешно выполнены.

Comment: Зачем что -то менять? Надо все лишь понять разницу. Это предложение взято из интернета. Вбейте в поисковике это предложение, вам придет этот текст. Просто нигде не объясняется смысл второго предложения.

Comment: Мне-то что вбивать и зачем? Смысл ПРАВКИ элементарно ясен.  ПРЕДСТАВИТЕЛИ  не выполняют обязательств, а только принимают их, выполняют же их ИСПОЛНИТЕЛИ , и только после того, как представители их примут. И еще я  Вам дополнительно объяснила , в чем конкретно заключается ошибка:  обстоятельство "на встрече" надо включить в причастный оборот.

Comment: Так ведь зачем править то, что исправлено? Я и так знаю,что ошибка есть. Меня интересовал смысл второго предложения,а не сама ошибка.

Comment: Возможно. Но никогда не лишне узнать, как эта ошибка появилась, в чем ее причина.